# Drupal 8 on IIS - error installing

Tags: php, iis, drupal, windows-server-2012

I already had Drupal working, but then I messed up with some module (layout_plugin) which is incompatible and broke the modules settings page. I tried to remove it different ways but failed. So I decided to start from scratch. I dropped the website DB and recreated the Drupal folder from default. Unfortunately now when setting it up it does all the installation but the last step after submitting email, credentials and time properties it ends with a super long error

```
Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. in GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->create() (line 57 of vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php).
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->create(Object, Array) (Line: 39)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 28)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 51)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 42)
GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 30)
GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 68)
GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 59)
GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 67)
GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 275)
GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object, Array) (Line: 123)
GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync('get', Object, Array) (Line: 129)
GuzzleHttp\Client->request('get', 'http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x?site_key=sMbmiei0HAVBa9TUtPGTQnY_kZwJIE2wWA4Kv0fbVyo&amp;version=8.3.7&amp;list=automated_cron%2Cblock%2Cblock_content%2Cbreakpoint%2Cckeditor%2Ccolor%2Ccomment%2Cconfig%2Ccontact%2Ccontextual%2Cdatetime%2Cdblog%2Cdynamic_page_cache%2Ceditor%2Cfield%2Cfield_ui%2Cfile%2Cfilter%2Chelp%2Chistory%2Cimage%2Clink%2Cmenu_link_content%2Cmenu_ui%2Cnode%2Coptions%2Cpage_cache%2Cpath%2Cquickedit%2Crdf%2Csearch%2Cshortcut%2Cstandard%2Csystem%2Ctaxonomy%2Ctext%2Ctoolbar%2Ctour%2Cupdate%2Cuser%2Cviews%2Cviews_ui%2Cstable%2Cbartik%2Cseven%2Cclassy', Array) (Line: 87)
GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('get', Array) (Line: 65)
Drupal\update\UpdateFetcher->fetchProjectData(Array, 'sMbmiei0HAVBa9TUtPGTQnY_kZwJIE2wWA4Kv0fbVyo') (Line: 160)
Drupal\update\UpdateProcessor->processFetchTask(Array) (Line: 131)
Drupal\update\UpdateProcessor->fetchData() (Line: 423)
update_fetch_data() (Line: 249)
update_cron()
call_user_func_array('update_cron', Array) (Line: 391)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('update', 'cron') (Line: 223)
Drupal\Core\Cron->invokeCronHandlers() (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\Cron->run() (Line: 75)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run() (Line: 1778)
install_finished(Array) (Line: 662)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 540)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. in GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->create() (line 57 of vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php).
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->create(Object, Array) (Line: 39)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 493)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::retryFailedRewind(Object, Object, Array) (Line: 147)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 103)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 43)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 28)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 51)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 42)
GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 30)
GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 68)
GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 59)
GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 67)
GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 275)
GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object, Array) (Line: 123)
GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync('get', Object, Array) (Line: 129)
GuzzleHttp\Client->request('get', 'http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x?site_key=sMbmiei0HAVBa9TUtPGTQnY_kZwJIE2wWA4Kv0fbVyo&amp;version=8.3.7&amp;list=automated_cron%2Cblock%2Cblock_content%2Cbreakpoint%2Cckeditor%2Ccolor%2Ccomment%2Cconfig%2Ccontact%2Ccontextual%2Cdatetime%2Cdblog%2Cdynamic_page_cache%2Ceditor%2Cfield%2Cfield_ui%2Cfile%2Cfilter%2Chelp%2Chistory%2Cimage%2Clink%2Cmenu_link_content%2Cmenu_ui%2Cnode%2Coptions%2Cpage_cache%2Cpath%2Cquickedit%2Crdf%2Csearch%2Cshortcut%2Cstandard%2Csystem%2Ctaxonomy%2Ctext%2Ctoolbar%2Ctour%2Cupdate%2Cuser%2Cviews%2Cviews_ui%2Cstable%2Cbartik%2Cseven%2Cclassy', Array) (Line: 87)
GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('get', Array) (Line: 65)
Drupal\update\UpdateFetcher->fetchProjectData(Array, 'sMbmiei0HAVBa9TUtPGTQnY_kZwJIE2wWA4Kv0fbVyo') (Line: 160)
Drupal\update\UpdateProcessor->processFetchTask(Array) (Line: 131)
Drupal\update\UpdateProcessor->fetchData() (Line: 423)
update_fetch_data() (Line: 249)
update_cron()
call_user_func_array('update_cron', Array) (Line: 391)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('update', 'cron') (Line: 223)
Drupal\Core\Cron->invokeCronHandlers() (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\Cron->run() (Line: 75)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run() (Line: 1778)
install_finished(Array) (Line: 662)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 540)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file. in GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->create() (line 57 of vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php).
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->create(Object, Array) (Line: 39)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 493)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::retryFailedRewind(Object, Object, Array) (Line: 147)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 103)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 43)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 493)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::retryFailedRewind(Object, Object, Array) (Line: 147)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 103)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 43)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 28)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 51)
GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 42)
GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 30)
GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 68)
GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 59)
GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object, Array) (Line: 67)
GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object, Array) (Line: 275)
GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object, Array) (Line: 123)
GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync('get', Object, Array) (Line: 129)
GuzzleHttp\Client->request('get', 'http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/8.x?site_key=sMbmiei0HAVBa9TUtPGTQnY_kZwJIE2wWA4Kv0fbVyo&amp;version=8.3.7&amp;list=automated_cron%2Cblock%2Cblock_content%2Cbreakpoint%2Cckeditor%2Ccolor%2Ccomment%2Cconfig%2Ccontact%2Ccontextual%2Cdatetime%2Cdblog%2Cdynamic_page_cache%2Ceditor%2Cfield%2Cfield_ui%2Cfile%2Cfilter%2Chelp%2Chistory%2Cimage%2Clink%2Cmenu_link_content%2Cmenu_ui%2Cnode%2Coptions%2Cpage_cache%2Cpath%2Cquickedit%2Crdf%2Csearch%2Cshortcut%2Cstandard%2Csystem%2Ctaxonomy%2Ctext%2Ctoolbar%2Ctour%2Cupdate%2Cuser%2Cviews%2Cviews_ui%2Cstable%2Cbartik%2Cseven%2Cclassy', Array) (Line: 87)
GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('get', Array) (Line: 65)
Drupal\update\UpdateFetcher->fetchProjectData(Array, 'sMbmiei0HAVBa9TUtPGTQnY_kZwJIE2wWA4Kv0fbVyo') (Line: 160)
Drupal\update\UpdateProcessor->processFetchTask(Array) (Line: 131)
Drupal\update\UpdateProcessor->fetchData() (Line: 423)
update_fetch_data() (Line: 249)
update_cron()
call_user_func_array('update_cron', Array) (Line: 391)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('update', 'cron') (Line: 223)
Drupal\Core\Cron->invokeCronHandlers() (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\Cron->run() (Line: 75)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run() (Line: 1778)
install_finished(Array) (Line: 662)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 540)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\drupal-8.3.7\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php" at line 40. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 140 of vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php).
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (Line: 163)
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->startNow() (Line: 234)
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->regenerate(, NULL) (Line: 173)
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->migrate() (Line: 557)
user_login_finalize(Object) (Line: 1785)
install_finished(Array) (Line: 662)
install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 540)
install_run_tasks(Array) (Line: 117)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)
```

I wonder how could I break it. When trying to remove that module I installed PHP Composer, GIT and drush (but it is somehow not connected to Drupal so not working). I suppose some of this broke it.

Comment: check your folder permissions for wherever the temporary file storage is

Comment: This may help: http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-8-windows

Comment: check your temporary path. It is correct? Exists?

Answer (score 1):

GuzzleHttp can't create temporary files to store the session

uncomment this ligne in php.ini file

;sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"

just delete the semicolon at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a **missing file(s)** problem.

To install basic Drupal 8 core, I recommend **downloading the .zip or .gzip from drupal.org**, placing it in the website docroot, and extracting the entire archive in place there. That is the safest way to be certain all the files get deployed.

Also be certain there is adequate disk space available to extract all the file in the Drupal 8 core package.

Then be sure your empty SQL is ready to go, and then run {site}/install.php and enter the database credentials when asked.

-

Also, before installing Drupal be sure that your server can serve a plain index.html file, which verifies that the basic server is working.

-

Once core is installed, be sure to install a nice looking free Drupal 8 theme like magazine_lite or showcase_lite, for a better idea of what a Drupal8 site can look like.